# Why wont the .on function work on my JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a jQuery function on a website that will launch a series of questions when a button os clicked, but when the button is clicked the prompts don't work.

```
<script>

$('submit').on('click', function() {
    var username = prompt("Please type your username");
    var password = prompt("Please type your password");
    var welcome = alert("welcome " + username);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your selector is bad. `$('submit')` looks for a `<submit/>` tag. You probably want `$('#submit')` for `<button id="submit">` or something like that.

Comment: @xdumaine the $("submit") selector is fine as long as it's the only submit button on the page.

Comment: If you don't want people guessing what your markup looks like for the submit button, then post it

Comment: @DanChill no, that's not true.

Comment: @xdumaine - yes you're right. Lapse of judgement. It would be <input type="submit"... so you should use $("input[type=submit]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'submit'` selector matches `<submit>` elements, i think you are looking for `input[type="submit"]`

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
    var username = prompt("Please type your username");
    var password = prompt("Please type your password");
    var welcome = alert("welcome " + username);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that script is firing inside of a DOM Ready handler:

```
$(function(){

Your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a complete question here, but I noticed that `'submit'` is not the name of a standard HTML element. Therefore, I'm going to assume that it's either an ID or class name.

If it's an ID, you should use `'#submit'`. If it's a class name, you should use `'.submit'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is probably incorrect. `$('submit')` will look for a `<submit>` element in your HTML, which is probably not what you want.

My guess is that you are looking for a click on an `<input type="submit">`, in which case you should use `$('input[type="submit"])` and not `$('submit')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your script end of body 
Or use ready function if you have to put it on top of your page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       // your code 
 });
```

Or youse above answer is it as same as ready function.

Comment: Only the `$( handler)` syntax is recommended, the other syntaxes are deprecated since version 3.0, and should not be used anymore.